# How to push notification from android to android via bluetooth

Tags: push-notification, wearables

i want implement a little program that can push notification from my phone to a smartwatch with inside android 5.1(it's NOT android wear).I don't want send throught firebase.... but throught bluetooth.Anyone know if this is possible and what i have to do?
Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Comment: Which version of the smartwatch? And did you look at the basic examples for it? This is pretty standard example case.

Comment: @weston - Thanks for your answer.I have a finow x5+ and yes,if there is a simple example to push notification into the watch.Thanks a lot.

Comment: So not a Sony Smartwatch then